How to import iOS library into my KMP app
I am trying to add a 3rd party iOS library as a dependency in my Kotlin Multiplatform app via cocoapods. The iOS library supports Objective-C so I should be able to import it but I get Unresolved reference when trying to import the library.
This is what I have tried:
kotlin {
    ios()
    cocoapods {
        version = "1.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "13.5"
        summary = "CocoaPods test library"
        homepage = "https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin"
        pod("FirebaseAuth") {
            version = "10.16.0"
            moduleName = "FirebaseAuth"
        }
        pod("razorpay-pod") {
            version = "1.3.7"
            extraOpts += listOf("-compiler-option", "-fmodules")
        }
    }
}

I'm able to import FirebaseAuth pod, but not the razorpay pod:
import cocoapods.FirebaseAuth // this works with autocomplete
import cocoapods.Razorpay // error: Unresolved Reference & no autocomplete


if a pod has hyphens/dashes in its name, like razorpay-pod, then look for the unhyphenated module name in the modulemap file. Its path would be like:
Pods/MyPod.xctframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/MyPod.framework/Modules/module.modulemap

with contents of the file like so:
framework module MyPodSDK {
 umbrella header "MyPodSDK.h"
 export *
module * { export * }
}

Use your module name, like MyPodSDK from above as the value for moduleName in your build.gradle:
pod("MyPod-iOS-SDK") {
          version = "9.17.2"
          moduleName = "MyPodSDK" // <- moduleName from above
}

After adding the pod in cocoapods block, sync the gradle project. Then open the Gradle sidebar & run the task

:shared:interopMyPodSdkIosSimulatorArm64

Have written about more troubleshooting steps at https://newsroom.shadowfax.in/unable-to-import-ios-library-in-kmp-via-cocoapods-try-this-ec0d960f464c
